# How do I set the name of an email sender via PHP

Tags: email, php

So I want the `from` field when an email is opened to be something like

`"Jack Sparrow Via somesite"` as opposed to an explicit email address.

I wondering how to set this in PHP's `mail()` function?

Answer (score 51):

You can accomplish this by using basic headers.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: Jack Sparrow <jsparrow@blackpearl.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'Reply-To: Jack Sparrow <jsparrow@blackpearl.com>' . PHP_EOL .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: **note:** when you want a `\r\n` its better to use `PHP_EOL` to make it compatible with all systems

Comment: Does this still apply here? As I understand it, PHP_EOL gives the line endings used by the server, but this should be specific to the standard for email headers rather than the server.

Answer (score 15):

You have to set your headers:

```
$to = "Someone@email.com";
$header = "FROM: Jack Sparrow <some@site.com>\r\n";
$message = "Your message here.";
$subject = "Your subject";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$header) or die();
```

Answer (score 3):

just use like this

```
$headers .= 'From: [Name of the person]'.'<'. $this->from .'>'. "\n";
```

in Header Section.

Answer (score 2):

If you use PHP Mailer from GitHub, then you do it by:

```
$mail->SetFrom("info@mibckerala.org", "MIBC");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$to = "Someone@email.com";
$message = "Your message here.";
$subject = "Your subject";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$header, '-f some@site.com -F "Jack Sparrow"') or die();
```

Just add the -f parameter to provide the sender's email and -F parameter to provide the sender's name to the mail(), all as a string.

**Note:** double quotes around "Jack Sparrow"

*Assuming that you are using sendmail on a Linux machine:*

You can find more detailed information by typing "man sendmail" in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean, but as you can see on [PHP.net mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

To add the name to the from section you need to send this in the headers. 
`From:Name<email@example.com>`